# why $p : \bigcup V_n \to U$ is continious?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Taken from Munkres book Page no :$333$

**Theorem $53.1$**: The  map $p : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$  given by  equation $ p(x)= ( \cos 2 \pi x  , \sin 2 \pi x) $is covering map

I have some confusion on Munkres proof

Munkres say that  $p : \bigcup V_n \to U$ is  continiuous + bijective

Also see the diagram given below

[image]

From  the diagram we can conclude that  $V_1 \cap V_2 \cap........\cap V_n= \emptyset$

This implies  $ \bigcup V_n$  is not connected

we know that continuous image of connected set is connected

So we will get contradiction

Now  my question is that

why $p : \bigcup V_n \to U$ is  continuous ?

Comment: You are correct that the continuous image of a connected set is connected. However, the inverse doesn't hold. Specifically, just because a set is not connected doesn't mean that it's continuous image is not connected. For example, for any space $X$ we have a continuous map $X \to \{*\}$, the constant map. Even though $X$ might be not be connected, it's image $\{*\}$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The continuous image of a connected set is connected, but the continuous image of a *disconnected* set need not be *disconnected*.

Indeed, look at the constant map $f(x) = 0$ from $X \to \mathbb{R}$ for your favorite topological space $X$. This will *always* be continuous (do you see why?) even though $\{ 0 \}$ is connected and $X$ might not be.

As a small aside, this function $p : \bigcup V_n \to U$ is only a bijection *on connected components*. You can easily see that the function is not injective, but thankfully that is OK. The notion of [covering map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) only asks for *local* homeomorphism-ness. That is, every point "upstairs" (in $\mathbb{R}$, in this case) should have a neighborhood (in this case, whichever $V_n$ contains it) which is a homeomorphism onto its image (in this case $U$) "downstairs" (in this case $S^1$). It might be worth rereading the definition of covering space a few times to make sure the subtleties make sense, because it's very fundamental (if you'll pardon the pun) going forwards in algebraic topology.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thanks u  @HallaSurvivor      that  mean  $U$  have  the discrete  topology

Answer (score 1):

Generally  $p$  is a constant  map for  each   $V_n$

$p(V_1)= p(V_2)=.......=p(V_n)=U$

Therefore $p$ is continious